# Getting download is not a function error while clicking the download button

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-5

I upload my code on gitlab.com here is the link...

https://gitlab.com/this-is-my-user-id-of-gitlab-account/download_button_problem/-/blob/main/stack.html

When I click on download button I'm getting download is not a function error on the console like this...

```
Uncaught TypeError: download is not a function
at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

I set **onClick** listener on every download button but didn't understand it's throw error.
Please help me figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: use Download uppercase "D". download might be reserved key word by DOM.

Comment: It's throw No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource error.. @Mehrwarz